# Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://mydomain.mysite.com/blah/blah.jsp does not permit cross-origin framing

Tags: experience-manager

We have a site running in HTTPS and are configuring XPM.  We've enabled Tridion CM to run HTTPS as well following the docs on SDL Live (http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_FC687109502D4F29BBC8E7222A9C117A).  We are now getting the following error when clicking the Tridion Site Edit button from the top left of the website page:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options:
>   https://mydomain.mysite.com/blah/blah.jsp does not permit cross-origin
>   framing.

[image]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is important to know that XPM actually loads yout website in an iFrame.  So if you have set your HTTP headers to disallow this, then the error occurs.

This answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10174077

We use IPlanet, so on the web server we removed the HTTP header restriction to disallow embedding our site into an iframe. This did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are not able to configure the Web Server to drop the header, a Chrome extension will do the trick as well:

> Source: https://gist.github.com/dergachev/e216b25d9a144914eae2
>
> Chrome Store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ignore-x-frame-headers/gleekbfjekiniecknbkamfmkohkpodhe